# Creating a woocommerce quantity shortcode for variable products

Tags: javascript, php, css

I am creating a product table for a variable product on my site. The table is on the product page and will display all variations of the product. Each variation has its own quantity field and add to cart button. I created a shortcode for the woocommerce_quantity_input to add the quantity field inside my table. However I ran into some issues:

1. The quantity field's width is set to the width of the page, therefore it does not appear in the table. ([Width issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMEgj.jpg))
2. The quantity field does not interact with the corresponding ajax add to cart button.

The quantity shortcode:

```
/*** Shortcode WooCommerce Quantity.***/ 

add_shortcode( 'product_quantity', 'woo_quantity_shortcode' ); 

function woo_quantity_shortcode( $atts ) { 
     
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array( 
        'id' => null 
    ), $atts, 'product_quantity' ); 
  
    if ( empty( $atts[ 'id' ] ) ) { 
        return ''; 
    } 
    $quantity=woocommerce_quantity_input( $atts['id'] ); 
 
    if ( ! $quantity ) { 
        return ''; 
    } 
  
    return $quantity->woocommerce_quantity_input();
}
```

For the width issue I tried adding a width property to the "quantity" in my themes plugin style.css

```
.quantity {
    width:71px !important;
}
```

For the add to cart button issue I tried adding this  javascript to my themes plugin function.js

```
    // Trigger event.
            $( document ).trigger( 'add_to_cart', [ thisButton, data ] );
            
            var product_id = $(this).data('product_id');
            
            var temp_number = $(this).closest('quantity_' + product_id).data('temp_number');
            config_json = getConfig_json( temp_number ); 
            var qtyElement = $( temp_number + ' #product_id_' + product_id + ' input.input-text.qty.text');
            var min_quantity = qtyElement.attr('min');//.val();
            if(min_quantity === '0' || typeof min_quantity === 'undefined'){
                min_quantity = 1;
            }
```

Neither of these solutions have worked. I'm not sure if the issue is with the shortcode or the javascript

Comment: `woocommerce_quantity_input` by default echos its result directly, so your assignment `$quantity=woocommerce_quantity_input( $atts['id'] );` leaves `$quantity` empty, and it is also the likely reason for the field appearing outside of the table. You need to set the third parameter to `false`, so that it returns the HTML it creates.

Comment: @Cbroe I've added in the three parameters  into '$quantity' '$qunatity=woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $atts['id'], false )'. I get a critical error on my site as a result. Is my syntax correct for woocommerce_quantity_input?

Comment: "critical error" doesn't tell much. Enable debug mode, and go check what the logs have to say about the _reason_.

Comment: I enabled debug mode and checked the logs, so far no issues have been shown.